# Scrolling of a Document

Tags: c#, document, scroll

I'm working on an application in c#, which reads a pdf document. As we all know we have hand tool in most of the pdf reader, which is used to scroll the document. My issue is when I use the hand tool to scroll the mouse, the speed of the movement of the mouse and the speed of the scrolling of the document is not synchronized. Not matter how fast or slow I move the mouse, speed of scrolling of the document remains same.

I need help in developing the logic for this.

Answer (score 1):

In your mouse move event, determine how far the mouse has moved, and scroll the document by that much.

Comment: Could you send me the code, as I'm using a 3rd party tools, I can directly implement that.